# Unit testing MVC app with Hangfire

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am trying to setup unit testing for MVC 3 controllers that make use of Hangfire using OWin. Under normal operations, Hangfire gets configured in the Configuration function of the main controller like this

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var sCon = ConnectionString.GetConnectionString();
    try
    {
        IUnitOfWork oUoW = UnitOfWorkFactory.GetInstance(sCon);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return;
    }
    app.UseHangfire(config =>
    {
        config.UseSqlServerStorage(ConnectionString.GetConnectionString());
        config.UseServer();
    });
}
```

I'm setting up HttpContextBase using Moq like this

```
private static HttpContextBase FakeAuthenticatedHttpContext()
{
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
    var user = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
    var identity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
    var application = new Mock<HttpApplicationStateBase>();

    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(user.Object);
    context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Application).Returns(application.Object);
    user.Setup(ctx => ctx.Identity).Returns(identity.Object);
    identity.Setup(id => id.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
    identity.Setup(id => id.Name).Returns("admin");

    return context.Object;
}

moBaseController.SetFakeAuthenticatedControllerContext();
```

How do I fake the call to Configuration to setup the Job Storage? I have been looking at the Hangfire documentation and they are a little cryptic in this area and mention that job storage should be set up something like this

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("<connection string or its name>");
using (new BackgroundJobServer())
{
   BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ProcessReport(oReportRequest, JobCancellationToken.Null)));

}
```

however GlobalConfiguration is not known anywhere in the controller or unit test.

I'm using Hangfire version 1.1.1 and OWin 2.1.

To summarize, I am looking for a way to mock the environment of a MVC 3 Method call, to setup Job Storage and Background Server transparently. i.e. how can I mock the controller so that when the method is called this has been setup.

This is generally how I call the controller in the unit test:

```
oViewResult = (ViewResult)moController.RunExport(oRequest);

Assert.IsNotNull(oViewResult, "Didn't return a view result!");
Assert.IsTrue(oViewResult.ViewName == "RunReport", "Didn't return a valid view name!");
Assert.IsTrue(oViewResult.Model != null, "No Model response!");

var oResult = (string)oViewResult.Model;
Assert.IsTrue(oResult == "Ok", "Export did not run as expected!");
```

Generally when Hangfire is called it is done like this in the controller

```
oTokens.Add(oReportStatus.ID, BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => ProcessReport(oReportRequest, JobCancellationToken.Null)));
```

Comment: Couple of things. Firstly, `GlobalConfiguration` is just a class with a bunch of static methods, I think you find it in `Hangfire` namespace. Secondly, why do you need to test anything to do with Hangfire? Surely you just need to test your job methods.

Comment: I don't need to test Hangfire, I need to test controller Methods that happen to make calls to Hangfire, i.e. I need to Mock the Hangfire environment, Job Storage, BackgroundServer etc.

Comment: Did you [read this](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/writing-unit-tests.html)? Instead of using `BackgroundJob.Enqueue()`, you should grab `IBackgroundJobClient` from the object factory/DI of your choice instead of using the static classes. That is, you'd be running `IBackgroundJobClient bjc = GetJobClient(); bjc.Enqueue(...);` Then you simply mock `IBackgroundJobClient`.

Comment: So you are saying I should be using the BackgroundJobClient in the controller to shoot off jobs instead of BackgroundJob, since it's mockable?

Comment: @aggaton Yes, as per the link *"But don’t worry – the BackgroundJob class is just a facade for the IBackgroundJobClient interface and its default implementation – BackgroundJobClient class."*. If you want to mock out Hangfire, you'll need to code against the interface only

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the answer, I got my test working. You should write that as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Placing this as the solution, as per @Rob's suggestion I changed all BackgroundJob.Enqueue() references to IBackgroundJobClient bjc = GetJobClient(); bjc.Enqueue(...); and mocked IBackgroundJobClient, and was able to get the test working that way.

Comment: but you cannot use schedule recurring jobs with `IBackgroundJobClient`..

Answer (score 0):

One way to test recurring job execution, assuming your code is something like `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<MyJobClassType>(recurringJobId: "my recurring job id", methodCall: x => x.MyMethodAsync(id, null), cronExpression: "my cron");`, is to do the following:

1. Setup in memory storage for your unit test class (NuGet package Hangfire.MemoryStorage), since I'm assuming you don't want to persist this to a DB.
2. Execute code that schedules recurring job
3. Get recurring jobs from storage and do asserts

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.MemoryStorage;
using Hangfire.Storage;
```

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void TestFixtureSetup(TestContext context)
{
    var jobStorage = new MemoryStorage();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseStorage(jobStorage);
}
```

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test_RecurringJob_Scheduled_When_MyTestCondition()
{
    // TODO: execute code that schedules recurring jobs

    using (var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection())
    {
        var recurringJobs = connection.GetRecurringJobs();
        // TODO: asserts
    }
}
```